# Difference between AWS CloudWatch and AWS CloudWatch Events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Was studying about Amazon web services and fundamentals when came across these 2 concepts:

- Amazon CloudWatch
- Amazon CloudWatch Events

Even while going through the official documents on AWS, I couldn't find a difference between the two even when Amazon mentions that they are different. Excerpt is:

- CloudWatch provides you with data and actionable insights to monitor
  your applications, respond to system-wide performance changes,
  optimize resource utilization, and get a unified view of operational
  health. CloudWatch collects monitoring and operational data in the
  form of logs, metrics, and events, providing you with a unified view
  of AWS resources, applications, and services that run on AWS and
  on-premises servers. You can use CloudWatch to detect anomalous behavior in your environments, set alarms, visualize logs and metrics side by side, take automated actions, troubleshoot issues, and discover insights to keep your applications
  running smoothly.

  [Documentation of AWS CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/)
- Amazon CloudWatch Events delivers a near real-time stream of system
  events that describe changes in Amazon Web Services (AWS) resources.
  Using simple rules that you can quickly set up, you can match events
  and route them to one or more target functions or streams. CloudWatch
  Events becomes aware of operational changes as they occur. CloudWatch
  Events responds to these operational changes and takes corrective
  action as necessary, by sending messages to respond to the
  environment, activating functions, making changes, and capturing
  state information.

  [Documentation of AWS CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html)

Comment: don't forget about the differences between CloudWatch, CloudWatch Application Insights, CloudWatch Evidently, CloudWatch Logs, CloudWatch RUM, and CloudWatch Synthetics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***CloudWatch***

CloudWatch is a monitoring service for your AWS resources. You can `log` your log files. By default the resources created within AWS logs in CloudWatch(CW). You can `monitor` the `performance` of resources too for example you can monitor how is the CPU utilisation of your EC2 instances. You can set `Alarms` for your resources
threshold and get an SNS alert on that. For example you can create an Alarm for your DynamoDB if Write capacity is exceeding. You can set an alarm for your billing too. So basically CW is used as a Monitoring solution.

***CloudWatch Events***

CW Events is also the part of CloudWatch. CloudWatch Events is helpful when you want to schedule something. Say you to want run your lambda every other day, you can create a `Rule` for that or you want to trigger your lambda by `Event Pattern`. There are bunch of services supported by CloudWatch Events, you can use anyone of them as your target not just Lambda. `Event Buses` is used to send your events to multiple accounts also. For example if you have a CICD account and every month you bake new AMI there, to notify all accounts you can use `Event Buses`, after getting the event from Event Buses other accounts can trigger some important tasks.